# Custom fonts in ckeditor

Tags: fonts, ckeditor

I am from nepal and obviusly would like to type in nepali in ckeditor.But ia have not been able to find the viable answer yet!!The code given in some other question works fine for showing the name in the drop down menu but the font doen't apply in ckeditor

Comment: Have you seen this page in the docs?  Does it help?

http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_uilanguage

Answer (score 0):

Add font definition into style customization by using `contentsCss`:

```
window.ckEditorConfig =
        {
            contentsCss: [
                '/customization.css'
            ],
            ...
```

For each font-family in your dropdown, alike:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Forum';
  src: local("Forum"), url("/fnt/forum-regular/Forum-Regular.woff2") format("woff2"), url("/fnt/forum-regular/Forum-Regular.eot"), url("/fnt/forum-regular/Forum-Regular.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("/fnt/forum-regular/Forum-Regular.woff") format("woff"), url("/fnt/forum-regular/Forum-Regular.ttf") format("truetype"), url("/fnt/forum-regular/Forum-Regular.svg#Forum") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!I will try it